# How I change the background color on product descriptions/reviews?

Tags: product, rwd-theme

On the bottom of the product page there is the part at the bottom that shows descriptions and reviews. I like to add a background image or change the default color to other than white. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Goto `style.css` at `skin/frontend/rwd/your theme/css` , and 
type this if you want to change the contents color:-

```
.product-collateral {
   background:(here give your desired color)
 };
```

type this if you want to change the heading tab's color:-

```
.product-collateral .toggle-tabs li
{
   background:(here give your desired color)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

go to these files "yourtemplatepath/catalog/product/view/description.phtml" and "yourtemplatepath/review/product/view/list.phtml"
 and find which the content css class , then go to your template style.css file and change the background color of classes

Comment: On the rwd theme I couldn't find these files